# Is there a generalization of the fundamental theorem of algebra for power series?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, power-series

Given the similarity between polynomials and power series, I was wondering if there is any generalization of the fundamental theorem of algebra for power series. I understand that it doesn't make much sense to talk of multiplicity when the roots are supposed to be infinite, but maybe there is something like this :P

Comment: The power series $\sum\limits_{n\ge0}\frac{x^n}{n!}$ defines a function that never assumes the value $0$. For analytic functions, the concept of multiplicity is surely well defined.

Comment: If you think of FTA as saying any nonconstant polynomial can be factored into linear parts, then there is a generalization of this to entire functions using infinite products. See the Weierstrass and Hadamard factorization theorems in complex analysis. The role of nonzero constants is replaced by functions $e^{g(z)}$ where $g(z)$ is a suitable entire function.

Comment: The introduction of the book [Nevanlinna’s Theory of Value Distribution](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/analysis/book/978-3-540-66416-1) makes a cases that Nevanlinna’s theory is a generalization of the fundamental theorem of algebra to holomorphic and meromorphic functions.

Comment: @KCd, nice, but I think the OP is interested in conditions on entire functions that guarantee the existence of a zero.

Comment: If one viewpoint doesn't directly extend, sometimes a different one does.  It might be good if the OP clarifies what is meant for the purpose of this question by "the fundamental theorem of algebra".

Comment: A generalization to power series of "any nonconstant polynomial over the complex numbers has a zero" is "any entire function not of the form $e^{g(z)}$ for some entire function $g(z)$ has a zero", but that may not be of much practical use since the way you typically know an entire function has that form is by knowing it has no zeros.

Comment: I was merely thinking of zeroes of a power series, honestly. But if there are other viewpoints of the FTA which can be generalised to power series then they would be interesting to know anyway.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One generalization of the fundamental theorem of algebra to entire functions is given by the [Little Picard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), which can be phrased as follows:

> If $f$ is a non-constant entire function and $w\in \mathbb C$, then the equation $f(z)=w$ always has a solution, except perhaps for a *single* value of $w$.

This statement generalizes the fundamental theorem of algebra, which can be phrased as follows:

> If $f$ is a non-constant polynomial function and $w\in \mathbb C$, then the equation $f(z)=w$ always has a solution.

Comment: However, I don't see right now how the Little Picard theorem implies the fundamental theorem of algebra.