# Is there a generalization of the fundamental theorem of algebra for radicals?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, radicals, riemann-surfaces, inverse-function

Some questions here ask for solutions of equations such as

[$$\sqrt{x-15} = 3-\sqrt{x}$$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1827941/163)

which then turn out to have no real solutions. However, when complex values are permitted, $\sqrt\cdot$ makes more sense when [both leaves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Square_roots_of_negative_and_complex_numbers) are considered and the [complex square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root#Algebraic_formula)

$$\sqrt{z} = \pm\left(\sqrt{|z|+\Re z} + i\,\sigma(\Im z)\sqrt{|z|-\Re z}\right)/\sqrt2$$

is used. Now is there any generalization of the [fundamental theorem of algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra) how many (if any) complex solutions equations involving radicals like the one above have if (or if not) both leaves are considered?

One [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/820327/163) mentions the [little Picard theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem), which states that a *holomorphic* function is either constant or takes all but one complex value. However, roots are not entire in $\mathbb C$ and include branch cuts, thus Little Picard doesn't apply here. What we do have here however is a [Riemann surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface)...

Comment: Since you're considering all branches, the equation is algebraic, so you need no generalization.

Comment: @egreg How so? Doesn't the theorem only work for polynomials?